# How to specify which node is being queried in Mongo ReplicaSet?

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

connection:

```
client = MongoClient(
    'localhost:27017',
    replicaSet='foo',
    readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
```

so, how to specify whether slave or master is used ? 
thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `readPreference` to either `primary` or `secondary` if you want to limit to the specific category. If need more granular control you can use [`tagSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#replica-set-read-preference-tag-sets) to limit the options.

To use the tag sets you have to:

- [Configure Replica Set Tag Sets](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/)
- perform query using specific [`readPref`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/) based on tag or use [`setReadPref`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Mongo.setReadPref/) on Mongo connection

Comment: Thanks a lot, if I set ```readPreference='secondaryPreferred' ``` , is there any method to prove the secondry is hit ?

Comment: sovled , I tried this  
`  db.system.profile.find()  `